# How can I use IF EXIST with a specific file type?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch script that will perfotm one of two actions based on if a specified filetype is or is not present. I'm using `If EXIST` and `IF NOT EXIST`, but I can't get these to actually detect if the file type exists or not. Here's my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST *.ini GOTO :NOPROFILE
IF EXIST *.ini GOTO :IMPORT

:INSTALL
COLOR 0B
TITLE Profile Installer
MODE CON COLS=43 LINES=2
cls
SET /P MENU="Do you want to install this profile (Y/N)? "
IF /I "%MENU%" EQU "Y" GOTO :IMPORT
IF /I "%MENU%" EQU "N" GOTO :CANCELLED
IF /I "%MENU%" EQU "Y" GOTO :INVALID
IF /I "%MENU%" NEQ "N" GOTO :INVALID

:IMPORT
MKDIR "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Config\Profiles\Wiimote"
COPY "*.ini" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Config\Profiles\Wiimote"
COPY "*.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Config\Profiles\Wiimote"
GOTO :DONE

:INVALID
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Error!
SET msgboxBody=Please enter one of the above menu options...
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
Error.exe "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :INSTALL

:DONE
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Notice
SET msgboxBody=The profile has been successfully installed.
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
Error.exe "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :OPEN

:OPEN
%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Dolphin Emulator\Config\Profiles\Wiimote"
GOTO :END

:CANCELLED
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Notice
SET msgboxBody=Installation cancelled, closing...
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
Error.exe "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :END

:NOPROFILE
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Error!
SET msgboxBody=No INI profile detected, closing...
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
Error.exe "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :END

:END
```

Is this possible, how do I achieve my goal by declaring a specific file type or extension?

Comment: Try `IF EXIST "*.ini"`. Try also with the folder path.

Comment: I already tried wrapping the extension definiton in quotes @harrymc, no dice.

Comment: Your above lines do work here, without seeing your compplete code it's difficult to help. Without a path it checks the current folder, not neccessarily the one the batch resides in.

Comment: I'm checking the working directory @LotPings (`.\`). I tried using the path variable as well but it changed nothing. This is just an initial check I'm running in my script.

Comment: I agree with @LotPings. The code you posted in your question works just fine. You will need to show us your entire code.

Comment: It's IMO still unclear **where** you want to check for the  *.ini files, in case you want to refer to the same folder where the batch file is, use `If exist "%~dp0*.ini" GOTO :IMPORT`

Comment: I have added my full code @Squashman, but I must say that I don't understand how this should work as others have stated. I initially thought a simple mechanic like this would but it simply does not. Perhaps I am missing something or have overlooked a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use following command

```
SET IS-PROFILE=NO
FOR %%f IN (*.ini) do SET IS-PROFILE=YES
```

and then test IS-PROFILE

As proposed in comment, you can break the loop using following command

```
SET IS-PROFILE==NO
FOR %%f IN (*.ini) do (
set IS-PROFILE=YES
echo %%f - File containing INI exists
exit /b
)

IF '%IS-PROFILE%'=='NO' (
echo NO File contains INI type 
)
```

I have tested on my PC on Windows 10 and this work fine.

Comment: instead of looping through all the files you can just set the variable and break early, or jump to a place that contains the "exist" branch

Comment: Yes, but breaking a FOR loop in DOS is tricky

Comment: the OP is using Windows, not DOS, and in cmd there are many ways to exit a for loop. It's often used to get the first result in a list or the [first line in a text filefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130209/995714). [Exiting out of a FOR loop in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6728798/995714)